# I need to create a column with the distance between two coordinates in polars

Tags: python-polars

I don't understand how UDFs work in polars. Will it return a df o lf? I want to work as lazily as posible.

I want to use the geodesic function from geopy.

Here is an example of how it would look in pyspark.

```
    @F.udf(returnType=FloatType())
    def geodesic_udf(a, b):
        return geodesic(a, b, ellipsoid="WGS-84").km

    df = df.withColumn("distance", geodesic_udf(F.array("lat_1", "lon_1"), F.array("lat_2", "lon_2")))
```

I have the coordenates stored in one column with the two coordinates separated by a comma in a string. I already transformed them into one column per number, and filled the nulls with 0.

```
    df = df.with_columns(((((pl.col(col1).str.split(by=",")).arr.get(0)).str.strip()).cast(pl.Float64).alias("lat_1")),
                         ((((pl.col(col1).str.split(by=",")).arr.get(1)).str.strip()).cast(pl.Float64).alias("lon_1")),
                         ((((pl.col(col2).str.split(by=",")).arr.get(0)).str.strip()).cast(pl.Float64).alias("lat_2")),
                         ((((pl.col(col2).str.split(by=",")).arr.get(0)).str.strip()).cast(pl.Float64).alias("lon_2")))

    nulls_to_fill = ["lat_1", "lon_1", "lat_2", "lon_2"]
    for column in nulls_to_fill:
        df = df.with_columns(pl.col(column).fill_null(0))
```

If there is a more efficient way of doing this let me know.

I am quite new to polars, and I already got stuck trying to create the tuples needed for the function.

`df.with_columns(pl.map(["lat_1","lon_1"],lambda s: tuple((s[0],s[1]))).alias("position1")).collect()`

I ran out of memory while running this.

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer from avimallu

You should be able to create a struct instead of a tuple. Or a list column. Or a np.array column. Here's my personal preference (with benchmarks from this Stackoverflow question!), where I create a list column:

The benchmark from the linked Stackoverflow question:

```
def distance(s_lat, s_lng, e_lat, e_lng):

    # Approximate radius of earth in km
    R = 6373.0
    s_lat = s_lat * np.pi/180.0
    s_lng = np.deg2rad(s_lng)
    e_lat = np.deg2rad(e_lat)
    e_lng = np.deg2rad(e_lng)

    d = np.sin((e_lat - s_lat)/2)**2 + np.cos(s_lat)*np.cos(e_lat) * np.sin((e_lng - s_lng)/2)**2

    return 2 * R * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(d))
```

Create two Polars functions that return expressions:

```
def d2r(deg: str) -> pl.Expr:
    return pl.col(deg) * np.pi / 180

def polars_haversine(s_lat: str, s_lng: str, e_lat: str, e_lng: str) -> pl.Expr:
    R = 6373.0

    s_lat = d2r(s_lat)
    s_lng = d2r(s_lng)
    e_lat = d2r(e_lat)
    e_lng = d2r(e_lng)

    return (2 * R * (
        (e_lat - s_lat).truediv(2).sin().pow(2) + 
        (s_lat.cos() * e_lat.cos()) * (e_lng - s_lng).truediv(2).sin().pow(2))
            .sqrt().arcsin())
```

Create some dummy data for benchmarking:

```
s_lat = np.random.randint(-90, 90, 1000000)
s_lng = np.random.randint(-180, 180, 1000000)
e_lat = np.random.randint(-90, 90, 1000000)
e_lng = np.random.randint(-180, 180, 1000000)

DF = pl.DataFrame({
    "s_lat": s_lat,
    "s_lng": s_lng,
    "e_lat": e_lat,
    "e_lng": e_lng})
```

Verify that both functions return similar results (similar because we have floating point multiplication, so values will not always be exact, and rounding to five decimal points):

```
np.all(
    np.round(DF.select(polars_haversine("s_lat", "s_lng", "e_lat", "e_lng")).to_numpy()[:, 0], 5) == 
    np.round(distance(s_lat, s_lng, e_lat, e_lng), 5))
```

Finally, running benchmarks (on my modest machine):

```
>>> %timeit distance(s_lat, s_lng, e_lat, e_lng)
40.3 ms ± 725 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
>>> %timeit DF.select(polars_haversine("s_lat", "s_lng", "e_lat", "e_lng"))
19.9 ms ± 58.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Looks like Polars is about twice as fast, which is pretty great in my opinion. You chose helluva nice question to learn Polars with!

Read your Stackoverflow question later - I wouldn't recommend directly using an external function with Polars,
especially one that takes a long time to calculate like geodesic, since it'll still be done via Python and consequently will be slow, although you can do this like so:

```
(
    DF.select(
        pl.col("s_lat").arr.concat("s_lng").alias("t1"),
        pl.col("e_lat").arr.concat("e_lng").alias("t2"))
    .with_columns(pl.struct("t1", "t2").alias("t").apply(lambda x: dist.geodesic(x["t1"], x["t2"])))
)
```

I reduced the length of arrays to 100 for benchmarking the above case, which didn't quite work out well:

10.7 ms ± 172 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
So I guess if you want to trade accuracy for speed, you're good. If not, then I don't think Polars will exactly help here - unless you can re-write geodesic itself in Polars expression format.